# Convert array of int to array of chars - Python

Tags: python, arrays, int, chars

I am trying to convert a set literal of integers into that of chars.

For example, if the array {0,1} is given as an input, I would like to firstly check if the individual elements are chars and if not convert them into chars so that I get {'0', '1'}

So far I have tried:

```
for i in alpha:

    i = str(i)
```

Where alpha is my array. However this does not change the overall array alpha.

Can sometime please give me an idea of how I can do this.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `map` function to convert a list of integres to list of strings , how ever `map` function retruns a `map object` so I used a `list` function to convert that to a list and assgin to first list (alpha) :

```
alpha = [1,2,3,4]    
alpha = list(map(str,alpha))
alpha # ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
aa=['1','2','3','3','4']
aa=np.array(aa).astype('str').tolist()
aa # ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Comment: Please consider including detailed explanations along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `for i in alpha` **i** gets a copy of elements from alpha.

But you need to modify elements which you can do as suggested by Arman or if you want to modify your code then:

```
for indx, i in enumerate(alpha):
    alpha[indx] = str(i)
```